# checkbox how to implement - android recyclerview

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

I want to implement my onItemSelected so that when the user click the checkbox it will be mark as "checked"
and then update the column DBContract.EntryColumns.IS_CHECKED to checked (set it to 1). Everything is working fine but the problem is I don't know how to
implement onItemSelected method. Please can someone show me how to fix this.

Here is my Activity and list_item_book.xml where the CheckBox is defined.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        BookAdapter.OnItemClickListener,
        View.OnClickListener {

    private BookAdapter mAdapter;
    private CheckBox mCheckBox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAdapter = new BookAdapter(null);
        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }


    /* This method will be called when I Click on checkboxes */
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(boolean active, int position) {

        //what should I write here?

        //  DBContract.EntryColumns.IS_CHECKED

    //

    }  
}
```

//list_item_book.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map checkboxes to IDs and store it to Map<Checkbox, Integer>. And then just set listener on checkboxes. (Assume `checkbox` variable has `Checkbox` type)

```
CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener listener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                // Get the ID here
                int id = yourMapCheckboxToId.get(buttonView);
                // ... do what you are going to do having ID
            }
        }
    };
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
```